# Mysql table with 20Mil rows, and statistics getting out of date

Tags: mysql, optimization, statistics

I have a relatively simple myisam table in MySql which currently has about 20M rows.

I insert about 200k rows a night.

There are 3 indexes, one with 5 parts for a lookup, and 1 on the date technical key, and one on another technical key with very low cardinality.  The server version is 5.0.45

What I'm finding is that a query which should be using the date key (relatively high cardinality), is actually using the low cardinality key, and therefore going very slowly.  If I analyze the table, then it works as expected.  But I don't understand why I should have to analyze the table so frequently??  At the moment it seems I need to do it weekly - Is that normal?

(There are no updates/deletes in this table)

Rgds,
Dan

Comment: Can you post the query that's giving you the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mysql INDEX HINTS if it is not selecting the right index. For more information check [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-hints.html).

Comment: Shouldnt it do this for me though?  I come from an Oracle background and there the stats generally remain correct, and therefore the queries work as expected.  Maybe i'm missing some manual step to do with statistics in MySQL - Does the process have to be managed more than it is with Oracle?